# Function satisfying $f(z) = 1 + z f\left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right)$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, recurrence-relations

> Iterate the following equation to obtain an explicit formula for $f( z)$:
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> f( z) = 1 + z f\left( \frac{z}{1 + z}\right)
> .\end{align*}
> $$

Iterating this equation one obtains
$$
\begin{align*}
f( z) = \sum_{n \geq 0}^{} \frac{z^{n}}{\prod_{k = 0}^{n - 1} ( 1 + kz)}
.\end{align*}
$$
I wonder know whether this is already "explicit" enough or whether it can be simplified
even further.

Comment: You have to study convergence of the series.

Comment: In terms of the [first Kummer function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2) $$
f\left( {\frac{1}{w}} \right) = 1 + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{w(w + 1) \cdots (w + n)}}}  = 1 + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\Gamma (w)}}{{\Gamma (w + n + 1)}}}  = 1 + \frac{{M(1,w + 1,1)}}{w}.
$$

Comment: @Gary see my answer.

Comment: I think we need to assume continuity at most points, since the equation can only force values for algebraic $z$.

Answer (score 3):

Substituting $z\mapsto\frac1z$ in the functional equation and iterating yields
$$f(1/z)=1+(1/z)f(1/(z+1))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{z^{\overline n}}$$
which [DLMF 8.11.4](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11#E4) simplifies to
$$f(z)=e\gamma(1/z,1)+1$$
where $\gamma$ is the lower incomplete gamma function. $f$ has simple poles at the negative reciprocals of the positive integers; this can be seen by attempting to expand the functional equation at those points.

Taking the one-sided derivatives at $0$ from above reveals that $f$ is the *ordinary* generating function for a shifted, sign-alternated version of the Rao Uppuluri–Carpenter numbers [A000587](https://oeis.org/A000587):
$$f(z)=1+z+z^2-z^4+z^5+2z^6-9z^7+9z^8+50z^9-267z^{10}+\cdots$$